# MainActivity.java got corrupted in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on project in **Android studio**. But after adding a .jpg file in resources my `MainActivity.java` got corrupted and looks like below (See picture). [Screen shot of MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVlIh.png)

Is there any solution to recover my file?

Comment: You should use a VCS

Comment: @Kannan: try File->Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: Did you by mistake drag & drop the image on the MainActivity.java file? I feel it looks more like you trying to open an image. It shows up encoded file.

Comment: @bozzmob , iam just tried to add a jpg file in resources using explorer, after restart mainactivity is changed like this

Comment: We need a [mcve] in order to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

In AndroidStudio you can check **VCS -> Local History -> Show History**

Hopefully you can find there your code.

Comment: In History there is only white spaces

Comment: I'm sorry, if your are not using any version control system (like git), your code is lost.

Comment: Deleted the MainActivity and created a new MainActivity.java file but got another error Default activity not found,This is my manifest file:
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>

Comment: It is different question... But anyway, did you create new MainActivity in the correct package?